# Different instances for the same Fixture using INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, googletest

Can we have two different instances for the same TEST FIXTURE using INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. Here is an elementary example:

**gtester.cpp**

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <string>

class my_fixture :
    public ::testing::TestWithParam<std::string> {
};


INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Colours,my_fixture,
    ::testing::Values("red", "green", "blue"));

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Shapes,my_fixture,
    ::testing::Values("square", "circle", "triangle"));


TEST_P(my_fixture, has_positive_size) {
    auto const & val = GetParam();
  ASSERT_TRUE(val.size() > 0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Compile:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -c gtester.cpp
```

Link:

```
$ g++ -o gtester gtester.o -lgtest -pthread
```

Run:

```
$ ./gtester
[==========] Running 6 tests from 2 test cases.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 3 tests from Colours/my_fixture
[ RUN      ] Colours/my_fixture.has_positive_size/0
[       OK ] Colours/my_fixture.has_positive_size/0 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Colours/my_fixture.has_positive_size/1
[       OK ] Colours/my_fixture.has_positive_size/1 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Colours/my_fixture.has_positive_size/2
[       OK ] Colours/my_fixture.has_positive_size/2 (0 ms)
[----------] 3 tests from Colours/my_fixture (0 ms total)

[----------] 3 tests from Shapes/my_fixture
[ RUN      ] Shapes/my_fixture.has_positive_size/0
[       OK ] Shapes/my_fixture.has_positive_size/0 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Shapes/my_fixture.has_positive_size/1
[       OK ] Shapes/my_fixture.has_positive_size/1 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Shapes/my_fixture.has_positive_size/2
[       OK ] Shapes/my_fixture.has_positive_size/2 (0 ms)
[----------] 3 tests from Shapes/my_fixture (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 6 tests from 2 test cases ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 6 tests.
```

Run the `Colours` tests only:

```
$ ./gtester --gtest_filter=Colours/* 
Note: Google Test filter = Colours/*
[==========] Running 3 tests from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 3 tests from Colours/my_fixture
[ RUN      ] Colours/my_fixture.has_positive_size/0
[       OK ] Colours/my_fixture.has_positive_size/0 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Colours/my_fixture.has_positive_size/1
[       OK ] Colours/my_fixture.has_positive_size/1 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Colours/my_fixture.has_positive_size/2
[       OK ] Colours/my_fixture.has_positive_size/2 (0 ms)
[----------] 3 tests from Colours/my_fixture (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 3 tests from 1 test case ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 3 tests.
```

Run the `Shapes` tests only:

```
$ ./gtester --gtest_filter=Shapes/* 
Note: Google Test filter = Shapes/*
[==========] Running 3 tests from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 3 tests from Shapes/my_fixture
[ RUN      ] Shapes/my_fixture.has_positive_size/0
[       OK ] Shapes/my_fixture.has_positive_size/0 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Shapes/my_fixture.has_positive_size/1
[       OK ] Shapes/my_fixture.has_positive_size/1 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Shapes/my_fixture.has_positive_size/2
[       OK ] Shapes/my_fixture.has_positive_size/2 (0 ms)
[----------] 3 tests from Shapes/my_fixture (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 3 tests from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 3 tests.
```

In a more likelife scenario:-

`my_fixture` is developed by programmer Alice, and implemented in a header file `my_fixture.h` and (if necessary) a library `lib_myfixture`.

The `Colours` tests are developed by programmer Bob, in a separate test-suite implemented in:-

**colour_test.cpp**

```
#include <my_fixture.h>

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Colours,my_fixture,
    ::testing::Values("red", "green", "blue"));

TEST_P(my_fixture, ...) {
    ...
}

...
```

which is built like:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -I/my_fixture/include/path -c colour_test.cpp
$ g++ -o colour_test colour_test.o -L/my_fixture/lib/path -lmy_fixture -lgtest -pthread
```

And the `Shapes` tests are developed by programmer Carol, in another separate
test-suite, implemented in the same way.

**Later**

> What I wanted to know is if it is possible to couple an instantiation with specific TEST_Ps... and another one coupled with another set of TEST_Ps for the same test fixture.

No, you can't do that, because a `TEST_P(fixture,description)` is bound to
`fixture`, not to an instantiation of `fixture`. But given any fixture it is
trivial to make two functionally identical fixtures that are instantiated differently,
e.g.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <string>

class my_fixture :
    public ::testing::TestWithParam<std::string> {
};

class colours_fixture : public my_fixture {};
class shapes_fixture : public my_fixture {};


INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Colours,colours_fixture,
    ::testing::Values("red", "green", "blue"));

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Shapes,shapes_fixture,
    ::testing::Values("square", "circle", "triangle"));


TEST_P(colours_fixture, has_positive_size) {
    auto const & val = GetParam();
  ASSERT_TRUE(val.size() > 0);
}

TEST_P(shapes_fixture, has_positive_size) {
    auto const & val = GetParam();
  ASSERT_TRUE(val.size() > 0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
```

Comment: Hi Mike, 
Thanks for your answer; but i think my question was not clear enough.
What I wanted to know is if it is possible to couple a an instantiation with  specific  TEST_Ps (an instantiation of the same test fixture coupled with a pool of parametrized tests. and another one coupled with another set of TEST_Ps for the same test fixture).
Thanks!

Comment: @TaharHARAZ See extended answer